# Non-speech applications of deterministic all-pole models?

Tags: discrete-signals

I am enjoying reading (a used copy of) [*Statistical Digital Signal Processing and Modeling*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Statistical+Digital+Signal+Processing+and+Modeling-p-9780471594314) by [Monson Hayes](https://mhh3.ece.gatech.edu/).

A considerable chunk of the fourth chapter is devoted to *deterministic* all-pole modeling. I think that I understand the value of such deterministic models to designing filters and to synthesizing *voiced* speech (when the input to the all-pole filter is a deterministic pulse-train, as opposed to synthesis of *unvoiced* speech, when a stochastic input is used).

Are there other applications for deterministic all-pole models? I am interested in particular in applications for which the model parameters are computed repeatedly, requiring fast algorithms.